# 404 image react router dom link with parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
  import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

  <PageRoute exact page={GamesPage} path='/games/:type' config={config} />
```

When I try to get image on the page by using route with parameter , it returns `404` . But when I try to get image by using :

```
 <PageRoute exact page={GamesPage} path='/games' config={config} />
```

It works correct . I have tried to find the issue , tried to do `strict`  mode , but it return the same `404` error .

Browser try to find files by this route:

> http://localhost:8080/games/img/slots/banner.jpg

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "When I try to get image on the page by using route with parameter"?

Comment: I can't find out why when I try to get image on the page with absolute route , I get it , when route it relative , it don't return image , and return me 404 , I want to find out what should I do to change it , or it isn't possible ?

Comment: How is your `img` tag written? Maybe you have to add a `/` at the start of the `src` attribute.

Comment: img/slots/banner.jpg i try to get it in this way , you mean pass it like this /img/slots/banner.jpg ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Try that. If you don't have a `/` at the start, it will try to get it relative to your current URL, which might not be what you want.

Comment: man , you save my day )) thanks you a lot)

Comment: /img/slots/banner.jpg  - this is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it works on one route but not on the other, that indicates that you are trying to get the image relative to the current URL.

Add a `/` at the start of the `src` attribute of the `img` element and it should work as expected.

**From:**

```
<img src="img/slots/banner.jpg" />
```

**To:**

```
<img src="/img/slots/banner.jpg" />
```